# How to check if the particular version of Flash is installed

Tags: c#, flash, windows-7

My program is a 64-bit C#.NET application running on Win 7.

I want to check if the 64-bit Flash Player version "10.2.161.23" is installed in my system or not.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Macromedia\FlashPlayer\FlashPlayerVersion (REG_SZ, returns 11.0.0.58~installVector=1 on my machine.)

**EDIT:** On 64-bit machine, you need to look into 64-bit registry with HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Macromedia\FlashPlayer\FlashPlayerVersion.

Comment: I used the C# code to check for the registry location, if flash is there or not.  But SINCE MY APPLICATION IS A 64-BIT APPLICATION IT IS NOT WORKING. CAN YOU PLZ LET ME KNOW WHAT C# CODE SNIPPET SHOULD I USE INSIDE MY 64-BIT APPLICATION.

Comment: Why trust me when there are docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx